# Opening a file not working

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    ifstream input_file("DataStuff.txt", ios::in);
    //trying to open the notepad file named DataStuff.txt
    if(!input_file){ 
        cerr << "Error" << endl; exit(1); 
    } 
    else{ 
        cout << "good 2 go" << endl; 
    } 

}
```

Comment: And you know it is not working because?  Do you expect the file to open up?

Comment: no i have a line of code that stack overflow did not let me post that was if(!input_file){
        cerr << "Error" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        cout << "good 2 go" << endl;
    }

Comment: I added that into your question

Comment: What's your compiler/platform and how do you run? I'm sure that it's "yet another working folder issue".

Comment: I am using CodeLite as a platform with G++ as the compiler

Comment: Nothing to do with notepad actually, removed the tag.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::ifstream input_file("DataStuff.txt", ios::in);
  if (input_file) {
    std::cout << "ok\n";
  } else {
    std::cerr << "error: " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output should give you some idea what is going on. Most likely the file doesn't exist or the permissions are incorrect.

Further explanation: If the file couldn't be opened then the constructor for `std::ifstream` sets `errno` to a value indicating what the error was. You can access strings describing the error using the `strerror()` function (defined in `<cstring>`).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much this worked out for me and the DataStuff.txt file is now opening up.

Comment: Spare us the suspense and let us know what the problem was!

Answer (score 0):

*"Opening a file"* is used in the sense that there is a connection established between the file: `"DataStuff.txt"` and your program, by the input stream, `ifstream` object named `input_file` which allows you to read from the file.

One possible cause for the file to not open is if it doesn't exist (including wrong name).

Another cause is if the file permissions do not allow access, for example if you are not owner of the file and its set to private.

To get more information about the actual cause you should probably acquaint yourself with stream [`rdstates`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdstate/) and integrate them in your code to check the state of the stream after you try to open it.